# Chinese characters encoding issue with Spring-MVC / Java

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I have a JSP with a field where i type in chinese characters and submit the form `document.forms[0].submit();` , but once i submit the form, the value that the controller sees is messed up e.g. (æ¸¬è©¦å°ˆç”¨)

*Value of the field before submitting:*
[image]

*Value in the controller after submitting:*

[image]

This is at the top of my JSP file, but the browser (firefox 60) is probably ignoring it.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8; encoding=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Most of the solutions ive seen has to do with editing server.xml / web.xml in the apache-tomcat config folder, but i would like to know if I am able to fix this from my java application. Ive also tried setting this in my pom.xml file, but it doesnt seem to work

```
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

Comment: “…the value that the controller sees is messed up e.g. (æ¸¬è©¦å°ç¨)” How can you tell?  How are you obtaining the data in your code?  How are you examining it?

Comment: @VGR thats the value i get if i just print it out after submitting the form (have attached screenshot above of it in debug mode)

Comment: Please show the code for the controller and the code for the data class.